# Alguém me explica porque a variável dentro da função não é reconhecida em outra função do PHP no mesmo arquivo?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, classes, variáveis

Boa Tarde, eu chamei a variável de acordo com a função com `$qtdEstoque = api();` porem elá da erro, eu fiz esse mesmo teste sem a classe e funcionou o codigo é:

```
<?php

namespace Magenteiro\InventoryIntegration\Cron;


use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class InventoryUpdate
 *
 * @author    Ricardo Martins
 * @copyright 2018 Magenteiro.com/magento2
 * @package   Magenteiro\InventoryIntegration\Cron
 */
class InventoryUpdate
{
    

    /** @var Iterator  */
    private $iterator;

    /** @var StockRegistryInterface  */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /** @var ProductCollectionFactory  */
    private $productCollection;

    /** @var LoggerInterface  */
    private $logger;


    /**
     * InventoryUpdate constructor.
     *
     * @param StockRegistryInterface   $stockRegistry
     * @param Iterator                 $iterator
     * @param ProductCollectionFactory $productCollection
     * @param LoggerInterface          $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        Iterator $iterator,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollection,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->iterator = $iterator;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       
        $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create();
        $this->iterator ->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), [[$this,'updateItems']]);
    }

    public function api() {

        $headers = [
                'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjb2RfZmlsaWFsIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlIjpbImRyb2dhcmlhIl0sInRva2VuX2ludGVncmFjYW8iOiJ0cnVlIiwiY29kX2Zhcm1hY2lhIjoiMTA2MTEiLCJleHAiOjQxMDI0NTU2MDAsImlhdCI6MTY0MTQ4NzM0NywianRpIjoiMmM1ZmNlYWQtYjJhOC00OTVhLWIxZGEtMjU4YWU0OTBiNzZhIiwiY29kX3VzdWFyaW8iOiIxMDkiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJBUElfSU5URUdSQUNBTyJdfQ.niU8xVYgvfJThel_Kmk4tBEDTvTprU3sIfgGvLhMDyw'
            ];

            //INICIA O CURL
            $curl = curl_init();

            //CONFIGURAÇOES DO CURL
            curl_setopt_array($curl,[
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://homologacao.triersistemas.com.br/sgfpod1/rest/integracao/estoque/obter-todos-v1?primeiroRegistro=0&quantidadeRegistros=10",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            ]);

            //RESPONSE
            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            //FECHA A CONEXÃO ABERTA
            curl_close($curl);

            $array = json_decode($response);

           $qtdEstoque = array_column($array, 'quantidadeEstoque');
           
           return $qtdEstoque;
    
    }
        
    public function updateItems($args)
    {
       $qtdEstoque = api();
       
       
        var_dump($qtdEstoque);
        
    }
}
```

Eu já retornei o $qtdEstoque fiz tudo certo e mesmo assim aparece o segunte erro:

```
:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magenteiro\InventoryIntegration\Cron\api() in /var/www/html/app/code/Magenteiro/InventoryIntegration/Cron/InventoryUpdate.php:98
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magenteiro\InventoryIntegration\Cron\InventoryUpdate->updateItems(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Iterator.php(34): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/Magenteiro/InventoryIntegration/Cron/InventoryUpdate.php(62): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator->walk(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#3 phar:///var/www/html/n98-magerun2.phar/src/N98/Magento/Command/System/Cron/RunCommand.php(66): Magenteiro\InventoryIntegration\Cron\InventoryUpdate->execute(Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): N98\Magento\Command\System\Cron\RunCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 phar:///var/www/html/n9 in /var/www/html/app/code/Magenteiro/InventoryIntegration/Cron/InventoryUpdate.php on line 98
```

Alguem sabe como resolver? so sei que o erro esta em  `$qtdEstoque = api();`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas vi que está em escopo de objeto.
Se você vai instanciar essa classe em um objeto *$this*

***$qtdEstoque = $this->api();***

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado era isso que tava faltando, o this

Comment: Top! Marca a resposta como útil, assim quando mais pessoas tiverem dúvidas sobre escopo pode ajudar! Tmj